# Is there a best practice to forward method overrides while enforcing method execution?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Sometimes i have code along the lines of this:

```
    public abstract class A
    {
        protected abstract void DoSomething();
    }
```

```
    public abstract class B : A
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected sealed override void DoSomething()
        {
            SpecialFunctionalityOfClassB();
            DoSomethingInternal();
        }

        private void SpecialFunctionalityOfClassB()
        {
            // execute functionality i don't want an overwriting class to be able to 
            // break by not calling base.DoSomething()
            // redirect method execution to DoSomethingInternal
        }

        protected abstract void DoSomethingInternal();
    }
```

```
    public abstract class C : B
    {
        private void SpecialFunctionalityOfClassC()
        {
            // execute functionality i don't want an overwriting class to be able to 
            // break by not calling base.DoSomething()
            // redirect method execution to DoSomethingInternal
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected sealed override void DoSomethingInternal()
        {
            SpecialFunctionalityOfClassC();
            this.DoSomethingElse();
        }

        protected abstract void DoSomethingElse();
    }
```

Is there a technique i am not aware of to ensure an unbreakable method chain?

If i were to not seal the methods, someone could overwrite a method and forget to call the base version of it. Right now i wouldnt know another way of making sure that whoever derives from D will have all functionality executed the way i want it to, without a subclass breaking that structure.

Comment: What about composition instead of inheritance? This example doesn't seem to need inheritance at all.

Comment: @CarlosCoimbra Sadly i have got this issue in inheritance scenarios. Imagine a scenario where initialization has to be done in a specific order, where i want to provide an init hook, which does not depend on the implementer calling the base method to adhere to initialization order. I want to prevent that any middle class can break that chain of execution by forgetting to call the base method

Comment: If you're in full control of object instantiation, you can move initialization logic to another object and inject the fully initialized object into A/B/C classes. You're mixing [object graph construction with application logic](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). Usually objects should be in a valid state after calling the constructor without the need for some `init` method.

Answer (score 4):

One approach you could take is to make your `DoSomething` method final, and delegate to an overridable implementation method to perform the actual operation.  It could then set a flag when its version of the implementation method is called, which it would check for when it returned to `DoSomething` and throw an exception if it hadn't happened.

This approach is taken, for example, in the event handler methods of the Android API, to cause an exception if the implementor fails to call the superclass versions of `onCreate` etc.

Comment: sounds like an approach that i am looking for. could you provide a sample perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this...

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected void DoSomething()
    {
        // TODO: put class A logic here

        SpecialFunctionality(this);
    }

    protected abstract void SpecialFunctionality(A notUsed);
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    protected sealed override void SpecialFunctionality(A notUsed)
    {
        // TODO: put class B logic here

        SpecialFunctionality(this);
    }

    protected abstract void SpecialFunctionality(B notUsed);
}

public abstract class C : B
{
    protected sealed override void SpecialFunctionality(B notUsed)
    {
        // TODO: put class C logic here
    }
}
```

and so on...

Comment: I have no idea if your solution solves the OPs problem, but I would not want any solution that is passing a parameter called `notUsed` that is not used.  This seems like a major code smell to me.